# Run ANT file within the same workspace JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I want to **programatically run an ANT** file. I have used the next code:

```
File file = new File("path to file");
Project project = new Project();
project.init();

DefaultLogger logger = new DefaultLogger();
logger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
logger.setOutputPrintStream(System.err);
logger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);

project.setProperty("ant.file", file.getAbsolutePath());
project.addBuildListener(logger);
project.fireBuildStarted();

ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
helper.parse(project, file);
project.executeTarget(project.getDefaultTarget());
```

However, when I run the code I obtained the following **error**:

```
Problem: failed to create task or type epsilon.emf.register
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I am almost sure this problem appears because a **separate JRE** is being used. I need to setup the **same JRE of the workspace** (as we do in the Environment Tool when manually running an ANT file). *How can I change this option programatically?*

Answer (score 0):

Classpath issue, that is a typical error thrown when a jar is missing that implements a 3rd party ANT task.

Check your build file a look for the use of a task called "epsilon.emf.register"..

Answer (score 0):

For a brief solution to this problem please refer to the answers provided in this forum:

[Run ANT file with Epsilon tasks programatically](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1752115/#msg_1752115)